# How do you pull text out of a file and Email it as the body in Redhat?

Tags: linux, email, redhat, rtf

We have another piece of software saving data into an rtf file. We need to pull that data out and email it as the body of the Email. In SCO Unix we were able to use this:

```
mailx –s “Subject of email” email@example.com </text.rtf
```

But now that we are running Redhat the mailx package used is an entirely different package and will only attach the file as an attachment. Any help on this subject is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look for the `s-nail` package which is a fork of `heirloom-mailx` which is the package you are thinking of. (info at [S-nail](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/S-nail))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using the mail command instead.

```
$ mail –s “Subject of email” email@example.com < /text.rtf
```

some documentation can be found at https://www.binarytides.com/linux-mail-command-examples/ or using the "man mail" command.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem and solved it by faking mailx by a shell script. Change $PATH so that your "mailx" shell script is found first.
In this script we use sendEmail (Perl script, look here http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/) to send the mail:

```
sendEmail $ABSAUTH $(echo \-u "$(echo "$1"|sed -e 's/^-s//')") -t $2
```